# Complete action using dialog does not appear on some devices

Tags: android

I try to setup my application to be able to handle call event from system contact book. As it was described in documentation and answered to many similar questions I have added the following to my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ExternalCallLauncher"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        >
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I found out that this does not work on some devices.
It works in Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 (v 2.1), and does not work on Samsung Nexus S3 (v 4.1.2), Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (v 4.0.2).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch system event like a call, I suggest you to use a **Broadcast Receiver**.

Comment: I want to see the system "complete action using" selection dialog. If I understand it right the correct way to receive it is to declare the call action in the intent-filter. The problem is that it does not work on some devices.

Comment: I think in this case my application would not start at all. Though I tested, specified full package. Still does not work ((

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason. On a modern devices you can manage list of applications that can handle intents. You can do it via application settings or even through installed applications.

To clear defaults on Samsung Galaxy S3 go 
Home Settings > Application Manager > All > Phone 
and click the Clear Defaults button on the application settings tab.
Thanks to everyone.

UPD: Does work for S3, but does not work for Tab 10.1 and HTC. ((